# Error: can only concatenate str (not "numpy.int64") to str

Tags: python

So I used a decision tree for this code:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
Predictors = ['Subscription_Length','Call_Failures']
target = 'Churn'
Xs = customer_df[predictors].drop(index=[2])
y=customer_df[target].drop(index=[2])

classTree=DecisionTreeClassifier()
classTree.fit(Xs, y)

predict_y = classTree.predict(customer)
print(predict_y)
```

The output is [0].

When I try to draw the tree:

```
plot_tree(classTree, feature_names=predictors,class_names=y.unique(),filled=True,impurity=False)
```

It give mes the error:

> can only concatenate str (not "numpy.int64") to str

What do?

Comment: You defined `Predictors` (with capital P) in the second line. So, there should be an error when using `predictors` (with lowercase p) later when you do `Xs = customer_df[predictors]...`. Make sure the code you're showing is the actual code you were running.

Comment: Have you checked the data type of y? Guessing that's int and not string.